# MdePopover from angular material extended alternating above and below the target

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using MdePopover from angular material extended. Though x and y position are set to after and below using the attributes mdePopoverPositionX and mdePopoverPositionY, popover seems to be alternating above and below randomly in unpredictable fashion. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you make an example of this in stackblitz?

Comment: https://angular-evjxl9.stackblitz.io

Comment: The above link is rough version of the code that I used to achieve the popover. But the whole code is hosted in a iframe.

Comment: The issue here is that on clicking country/region button, popover opens below the searchcard (matcard). It is supposed to be opened at the bottom always. But it appears on top sometimes. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any progress on that question?

I can tell that position changes in cases where was a small place for popover to display, for example: trigger element in the bottom of the page. Tried to remove mdePopoverPositionX and mdePopoverPositionY or change their values - no result. :(